# P4 Shelve: What is actually saved?

Tags: version-control, perforce

I've used a number of version control systems over the years, and would say I've mastered SVN and Mercurial, but now I have a contract which requires me to use perforce. I have the basics under control, but occasionally I find an area where it's not clear exactly what perforce is doing.

Shelving changes is one of these.

This week I was in a situation where I was in the middle of a piece of work, and needed to change focus and work on a quick fix for someone. The old work was based on an older revision, and for the new piece of work I needed to be at the latest. So I...

- Shelved my current changelist.
- Updated my workspace to the latest revision
- Did my work
- Submitted it.
- Unshelved my original changes

I knew I was at the latest revision when I unshelved, but "That's OK, I needed to update anyway". What surprised me was that I didn't need to resolve any files. Unsure about why that would be I...

- Reverted my workspace
- Updated to the revision I'd originally been working at
- Unshelved my files again (I hadn't deleted the shelved version)
- Updated to the latest revision

At this point perforce asked me to resolve files, and it wasn't a trivial resolve (i.e. not one that could have been done automatically).

This has left me with questions:

- Is shelve just copying a file out of the way, and then copying it back? or is it storing a delta?
- Is it possible to cause other's changes to be undone by using shelve?
- How should I be working when this situation arises in the future?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

p4 shelve saves your files on the Perforce server, but doesn't remove your pending changes from your current workspace.  After issuing the p4 shelve command, you could have issued a p4 revert command to restore your workspace to the unmodified versions of your files, but from your description, it looks like you didn't do that.

So your update to the latest revision step (p4 sync) brought all the unopened files up to the head revision, but left your opened files as they were before you shelved them.

Your unshelve command had no real effect, since the files were already in the state you left them in before you shelved them.

As to your questions:

- shelve is copying the files (probably as a delta, but it's not important to me as a user) to a place where you (or your coworkers) can get them later, but it's not "out of the way," since it doesn't automatically revert your shelved changes in your local workspace
- shelving itself doesn't change the head revision of the file in Perforce; it's more like a micro branch.  However, when you unshelve a file, you may have to integrate the changes you made before shelving the file with changes that have been made to the file since it was shelved.  This can lead to others' changes being undone if you're not careful.
- Strenuously.

Comment: Your right. I hadn't realised shelve didn't put the changes "out of the way", but just created a snapshot. That's a different use of the verb `shelve` compared to other VCS. I'm still not clear why I didn't need to resolve files first time I updated to the latest revision though.

Comment: I think it means that the files you were editing had not been modified by anyone else, so there was not anything to resolve.

Comment: Thing is, a know that they were modified. I spent a couple of hours sorting out the conflicts when I did it the second time. That's the factor that kicked off this question. I have a feeling I'm not going to know exactly what happened now.

Comment: When you shelve, the server remembers the revision of the file you were modifying.  When you unshelve, conceptually, that version is changed to be the current on your workspace, and then your shelved changes are applied to it.  At that point, it is as if you had never shelved, and somebody else had since modified the file elsewhere. To resolve, get the latest version after unshelving, and then the conflicts/resolution options will be presented.